# Number of routes not passing in 3 points

Tags: combinatorics

> Given a coordinates system in which you can move in unit steps right or up, how many possible routes are there from $(0, 0)$ to $(k, n)$ while also not passing in any of the points $(z,c), (y,b), (x,a)$?
>
> $a<b<c<n,x<y<z<k$
>
> all parameters are in $\mathbb{N}$.

I managed to solve it with inclusion-exclusion but the solution is extremely ugly. Looking for a hint for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the solution? If it turns out there is a simpler form to the solution there might be an elegant solution, but if for example there is no closed form for the solution, then there might be less hope.

Comment: Near duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833857/grid-walk-with-restrictions-on-some-points?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

## Overview

The number of paths of east and north steps (${\bf E}$ and ${\bf N}$) on the grid without constraints is $T = {k+n \choose k}$.  You can envision this as $k+n$ slots (steps) into which you place $k$ ${\bf E}$ steps, where the rest must be ${\bf N}$.

Consider the first forbidden point, at $(x,a)$, which we call $A$.  The number of the total paths that pass through $A$ is the product of the number of legal paths from $(0,0)$ to $(x,a)$ times the number of legal paths from $(x,a)$ to the endpoint $(k,n)$.  Those numbers, multiplied, are $N(A) = {a+x \choose a}{(k-x)+(n-a) \choose k-x}$.

So you subtract these from the total number to find the total number of paths that do not pass through the first forbidden point.

A similar calculation holds for the second and the third forbidden points, $B$ and $C$.

However, for the full problem you must consider paths that don't go through *multiple* such points.

This is a straightforward matter of counting all the path segments that do or do not pass through the points, using the general mathematical formula above.  This is the technique of inclusion/exclusion.  Call the total number of paths $T$ (as above) and the number passing through $A$ as $N(A)$, and likewise for point $B$ and point $C$.  Then the total number of ways that avoid $A$ and $B$ and $C$ is:

$$T - N(A) - N(B) -N(C) + N(A \cap B) + N(A \cap C) + N(B \cap C) - N(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Comment: This is exactly how I solved it but you have to use inclusion exclusion don't you? Or is there another way?

Comment: Yep.  Inclusion/exclusion is what I meant by my last sentence.  Doesn't seem *too* ugly...